# c# wpf Eliminar más de un registro

Tags: c#, linq, wpf

Estoy trabajando con WPF y c#, deseo eliminar más de un registro de la BD sin utilizar foreach, no sé si haya alguna manera de utilizar linq para realizar esto.

Gracias de antemano.

---

La aplicación está en WPF y utilizo c#, desde la aplicación deseo borrar de la Base de Datos, más de un registro. Tengo demasiados registros en la base de datos por lo que hacer un foreach me consume memoria. Utilicé una lista de tipo la entidad de la que deseo borrar los registros y con linq aplico los criterios de borrado y lleno la lista. Deseo utilizar un .Remove o .RemoveAll para borrar directamente de la lista. 
Ya utilicé la ListaAutores.RemoveAll(x => x.Nombre== "Bob"); que Fran tuvo a bién contribuir, después de eso apliqué el .SaveChanges() no me marca ningún error, pero no se borran de la BD.

Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Hola Monet. Bienvenido a [es.so] Por favor lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionmaiento básico del sitio y tambien lee [ask] para saber cómo hacer preguntas de calidad. Has de explicar tu problema concreto con ejemplos. Un saludo

Comment: Si tu problema es la performance, el uso de `foreach` **SIEMPRE** va a ser más rápido que usar linq

Comment: Estas utilizando algun ORM?

Comment: Creo te refieres al EntityFramework. Utilizo ese...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor sería excluirlos de su propia lista, por ejemplo:

```
ListaAutores= ListaAutores.Where(x => x.Nombre!= "Bob").ToList();
```

Aunque esto cambiará los valores en lugar de borrarlos, si quieres borrarlos, usa:

```
ListaAutores.RemoveAll(x => x.Nombre== "Bob");
```

Comment: Hola Fran, gracias por responder pero es mejor esperar a que el OP detalle más su pregunta con los problemas concretos que tiene. Para asi, ayudarle a él y no hacerle su tarea., Un saludo

Comment: Aparte eso lo hace en memoria, por lo que entiendo el op pregunta por eliminación en la base de datos (BD).

Comment: Ya utilicé la segunda opción y después de eso el Entity.SaveChanges() pero no me borra de la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias a todos por su colaboración. Ya quedó resuelto con ésta línea de código...   Entidades.Entidad.RemoveRange(Lista.Where(x => x.idEntidad >= 1))    Por si a alguien le sirve...